# Data Direct ODBC for Interbase

Tags: odbc, interbase

Im trying to connect to an **interBase** database, using a program called Data Direct ODBC Driver for Interbase.

When i open Query1 which has fields from Table1 and Table1 is already opened, after some seconds i receive this message:

```
reserved error (-7713) there is no message for this error
```

and all the cells of (table1) shown "#deleted"

Can any one suggest how I may be able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated 1-27-2015**

Embarcadero who owns Interbase has an ODBC driver that is solid - http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28975

---

I agree with @SamuelKDavis - the DataDirect driver will sometimes return NULL for columns which definitely have values. You can test this by creating a query and running it repeatedly through an ODBC connection and it will intermittently return NULLs.

We had also tried the IBProvider driver but ran into character set errors which we could not figure out.

Interestingly, if you lookup the history of Interbase, you'll see Borland actually made Interbase open source back in July 2000 at which point it was forked off into an open source database called "FireBird" - [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_(database_server)#History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_%28database_server%29#History)

Now the cool thing here is that the drivers that work with the old Firebird (v2.1 and prior) will also work with Interbase 6.0 all the way up to Interbase XE 64-bit, probably because the open source fork had not yet deviated from its Interbase roots. So try using Firebird v1.7 ADO.Net driver - http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

The newer Firebird drivers for .NET 2.0+ however do NOT work with Interbase.

Answer (score 0):

Our company previously tried Data Direct with Interbase. It's terrible.

We suffered from random crashes using their driver, occasionally it would return nulls in the first column selected from the driver etc.

We moved to IBProvider (paid unfortunately), but have never come across an error since.